# Effect of TCP RST on page loading time for Javascript script src tag

Tags: tcp, image, pageload

I want to deprecate (turn off/not send HTTP responses) for some old HTML & JS code that my clients have installed on their pages.  Not all clients can update all of their webpages prior to when we deprecate, but I have the OK to deprecate.

Simple example of what the code can look like:

Customer domain, **customer.com**, has HTML & JS on their pages:

```
<script src="http://mycompany.com/?customer=customer.com&..."></script>
```

We are considering configuring our switches to send a TCP RST response on incoming deprecated requests to `http://mycompany.com/...`, so my question is, **are there any side-effects (stall page loading, for example) with the approach of configuring our switches to respond with a TCP RST on the incoming TCP connection?**  Obviously, I want the least (ie no) impact on a customer's site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have to think that `RST` is a fairly harsh mechanism to not reply to a single request. This request might be one of a hundred resources required to render one of your client pages, and if you tear down the connection, that connection cannot be re-used to request further resources. (See 19.7.1 in the [HTTP1.1 RFC](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2068.txt): "*Persistent connections are the default for
   HTTP/1.1 messages; we introduce a new keyword (`Connection: close`) for
   declaring non-persistence.*")

Each new connection will require a new [three-way handshake](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-way_handshake#Connection_establishment) to set up, which might add half a second *per failed request* to one of the two connections the client is using to retrieve resources from your servers. What is the average latency between your servers and your customers? Multiply that by three to get the time for a new three-way handshake.

If you fail the requests at the HTTP protocol level instead (`301`? `302`? `404`? `410`?) you can return a failure in the existing HTTP connection and save three-round-trips to generate a new connection (which might also be for a resource that you're no longer interested in serving).

Plus, `410` ought to indicate that the browser shouldn't bother requesting the resource again (but I have no idea which browsers will follow this advice.) An `RST`-ed resource will probably be re-tried every single time it is requested.

Comment: I have a question in regards to this quote from your answer "request might be one of a hundred resources required to render one of your client pages"....I can confirm that client's have at most 2 or 3 of our resources per page but almost always (99.9% of clients) have only 1 of our resources per page.  A single TCP connection only services resources from a single host, correct?  Assuming yes, tearing down only the 1 TCP connection that would be created doesn't effect the other non-mycompany.com resources?  I still like the 410 idea though and am looking at implementing this.

Comment: @mrk, you're probably correct: page request with no linked images, flash, movies, css, javascript, etc., will probably go as quickly with a `RST` as with a `410`. But, your users will get a "Connection to the server has been reset" error page, which encourages trying the connection again. A `410` "We're sorry, this doesn't exist any longer" is a little more forceful.